# Controller dotnetCore class not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm using .net core and have added some 4.5 libraries to my project. This works fine. But Visual Studio 2015 can't seem to find the "Controller" (which is a ASP.net core class) class.

My project.json file looks like this:

```
 {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "ClassLibrary1": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "ClassLibrary2": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

When declaring a controller, the "AspNetCore.Mvc" package is not found. And the "Controller" class is not found.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace WebInterface.Backend
{
    public class AppController : Controller
    {
    }
}
```

I'm suspecting that there is something wrong with my project.json but can't seem to find the problem. Any suggestions?

Update:

It seems to work, i can build the project but my inteli sense can't find the class, all the includes (system, Mvc) are not found. But when i build it gives no errors. Can also run the project. Any Idea's?

Comment: You are **NOT** using .NET Core

Comment: it is a not .net core class, but it is asp.net mvc core class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running this command in cmd in the directory where the project.json file is:

```
dotnet restore
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it says unable to tesolve ClassLibrary1 for .NetFramework, Version=4.5.2 and also for the other library. Any idea? Because building i visual studio (not including a Controller) works fine.

Comment: It seems to work, (not the command) i can build the project but my inteli sense can't find the class, all the includes (system, Mvc) are not found. But when i build it gives no errors. Can also run the project. Any Idea's?

Comment: no, try erasing the bin and obj folder and restart visual studio

Comment: Still no luck, any other sugestions?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but hopefully it helps someone...

I had a similar issue, my problem was that I named my folder "Controller" instead of "Controllers"

Once I corrected the folder name, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (ASP.NET Core 3.1) it was that `startup.cs` did not contain `MapControllerRoute()`

Adding `MapControllerRoute()` fixed it:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Taken from [add a controller to an ASP.NET Core MVC app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio-code)